# automatically update mySQL entries when files are changed

Tags: mysql, file, path

mySQL does not directly point to files. Instead, it can hold the path for the entries it databases. How can I design directories to automatically update appropriate entries in my database when modifications to those files are made (ie. reimplement `mv`, monitor directories, checkpoint system involving commit...) Given a sample table below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file
(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  path VARCHAR(150),
  size INT,
  creationDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
  modificationDate TIMESTAMP(8),
  destructionDate TIMESTAMP(8), 
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Everytime I move, edit or delete the file, I want the changes to automatically be reflected in `path`, `size`, `creationDate`, `modificationDate`, and `destructionDate`. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Mysql is agnostic of what `path` is, you'll have to update the table everytime you move, edit, or delete the file.

Comment: @abhinav Yes I am aware of that (although I never knew there was a term 'agnostic' for it). Surely there must be some ways around this. Perhaps tag and monitor files/folders, or capture calls to `mv`, `rm`...

Comment: I couldn't think of a better term to describe it :) Yes, you can add event handlers or use any other means in the language/framework that you're using. Eventually, the automatic update of the mysql table has to be done via your language/framework.`Mysql` itself does not provide the facility to track file modifications.

Comment: @abhinav I'll modify the question to reflect this

Comment: I think reimplementation of system procs doesn't ensure all activity on files, because file manipulation is possible by direct calls to underlying libraries. Moreover, suppose we've done proxy on any file modification. But to store information that file is modified your local DB **will modify** its own files, and that would be recursion.

Comment: If you're using linux, you could use inotify (http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). You can attach an event to when a file is moved, deleted etc. and then fire off a script or whatever to update your MySQL table values. I've never used it like that. Just an idea :-)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/50127/how-to-automatically-run-a-script-when-the-contents-of-a-directory-changes-in-li interesting read

Comment: @confused-demon it had occurred to me that it would be almost impossible to capture all functionality which changes files

Comment: @Flukey thank you very much. At this point that seems like the most promising. I believe I could use that with a SHA-2 hash function to find the entry on a database table. Yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using linux, you could use inotify (linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). You can attach an event to when a file is moved, deleted etc. and then fire off a script or whatever to update your MySQL table values. I've never used it like that.

Interesting read: https://serverfault.com/questions/50127/how-to-automatically-run-a-script-when-the-contents-of-a-directory-changes-in-li

Just an idea :-)

Though I'd add my comments as an answer. Whether it works is yet to be seen! Keep us updated.

Comment: sorry, sometimes I forget to mention I am using linux because I don't see the appeal of programming in a Windows environment.